# SSH Automation on server

Tags: sockets, ssh, automation, web-crawler

I am faced with the task of automating a process to interact with a server via ssh (it lauches a program, which can be navigated by keypresses).

At a certian point, it then will need to scrape some data, and once taken, enter a few more characters, and close the connection.

How would I approach such a problem? Any Programming language and linux/windows servers are pretty much fair game.

Is there any examples of a similar setup already in place? All feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

- C
  [libssh](http://www.libssh.org/)
  [libssh2](http://www.libssh2.org/)
- Java
  [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)
  [Ganymed SSH-2](http://www.cleondris.ch/opensource/ssh2/)
- Perl
  [Net::SSH::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SSH::Perl)
- Python
  [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/)
  [Conch](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedConch)
- Ruby
  [Net::SSH](http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/)